# Neo4j OGM unexpectedly deleting relationship

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have two connected entities

```
(ProductInstance)-[:INSTANCE_OF]->(Product)
```

I am now attempting to create a `ChangeroomSession`, which has a relationship to several `ProductInstances`:

```
public class ChangeroomSession {
    //other fields
    @Relationship(type = "INCLUDES", direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    private List<ProductInstance> productInstances;
}
```

Doing so results in the unexpected deletion of already-persisted relationships between `ProductInstances` and `Products` in my graph. For example, assume I have two `ProductInstance`s `p1,p2` (light blue) connected to a single Product (dark blue).

[image]

Next, I create a new `ChangeroomSession` and set its product instance list to contain both `p1` and `p2`. After performing this operation, the `ChangeroomSession` persists with relationships to `p1` and `p2` successfully, but the relationship between one of the `ProductInstance`s and the `Product` is unexpectedly deleted.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
List<ProductInstance> productInstances = findProductInstancesByIdIn(...)   
ChangeroomSession changeroomSession = new ChangeroomSession(productInstances);
this.changeroomSessionRepository.save(changeroomSession);
```

What is even more interesting is that if I set a breakpoint in the code execution, the `changeroomSession` object I am about to persist shows the missing relationship as being present. More than that, the returned object from the `.save` operation also shows it. It is only after the persist operation if I query the database again that the relationship is gone

[image: Debugger output]
[image: Debugger output]

This feels like unexpected behaviour - am I missing something? Why is this happening? Thanks!

Comment: Seems like an existing issue. https://community.neo4j.com/t5/drivers-stacks/super-frustrated-sdn-deleting-existing-relationships/td-p/45950

Comment: One thing that might be the cause is the wrong equals/hashCode implementation that would return the very same result for two different `ProductInstances`. But this is just a guess and I would have to get some context like which version of Spring Data Neo4j you are using. Also it would be helpful to get at least a peak into the `ProductInstance` (and `Product`) entity.